# PHP read file else another file

Tags: php, html, isset

I have problem here, if I start this script, server returns no value, I know this script isn't ideal for the server optimization, but Im   already without any ideas.
I need solution, If I choose Czech or English from my option, server returns correct values. Folders are in same address book. Will be glad for your time and help

```
<select name="example">
<option value="czech" name="czlang" selected="selected">Czech</option>
<option value="eng" name="enlang">English</option>
</select>

<?php
$czfolder = fopen("cz_data.txt", "r");
$enfolder = fopen("en_data.txt", "r");

if(isset($_GET["czlang"])) {
    echo(fread($czfolder, "100"));
      fclose($czfolder); }

if(isset($_GET["enlang"])) {
    echo(fread($enfolder, "100"));
      fclose($enfolder);  
        } 
?>
```

Comment: What are "correct values" here?

Comment: values from folders (cz_data.txt and en_data.txt)

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are going to have to be more clear about what your problem is, what values you are expecting, and so on. Also, Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks man, in a nutshell .. I need script, which know, which language is selected from option and will automatically change language by that option, in this moment isnt important content of folders, I hope its understandable :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<?php
// suggestion: always start with php.  Wait to output 
// anything until you are done processing everything.

// avoid non-existent key on inital run. Take action only on submission.
if(array_key_exists('example', $_GET)) {

  // using a switch statement is purely a matter of personal preference.
  // act on form input, then optionally die before printing form
  $choice = $_GET['example'];
  switch ($choice) {
    case 'czlang':
      print "show Czech...";
      //$czfolder = fopen("cz_data.txt", "r");
      //echo(fread($czfolder, "100"));
      //fclose($czfolder); }
      die;

    case 'enlang':
      print "show English...";
      //$enfolder = fopen("en_data.txt", "r");
      //echo(fread($enfolder, "100"));
      //fclose($enfolder);  
      die;
  }

}

// processing done; output html

?>
<h1>Choose Language</h1>
<form method="get">
  <select name="example">
    <option value="czlang" selected="selected">Czech</option>
    <option value="enlang">English</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Display" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put `name attribute` inside `<option>` tag. Put it in `<select>` tag instead.

**Try:**

```
<select name="lang">
<option value="czech" <?php ((isset($_GET["lang"]) AND $_GET['lang']) == "czech"?"selected":"");?>>Czech</option>
<option value="eng" <?php ((isset($_GET["lang"]) AND $_GET['lang']) == "eng"?"selected":"");?>>English</option>
</select>

<?php
if(isset($_GET["lang"])) {
    if($_GET["lang"] == "czech"){
        $czfolder = fopen("cz_data.txt", "r");
        echo(fread($czfolder, "100"));
        fclose($czfolder); 
    }
    else if($_GET["lang"] == "eng"){
        $enfolder = fopen("en_data.txt", "r");
        echo(fread($enfolder, "100"));
        fclose($enfolder);  
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: still no values

Comment: Is the `<select>` tag inside a `<form>` tag?

Comment: Do those file exist and have contents?

Comment: Yes, <select> is in <form> tag and files exists and have data, they are in same adress book like index.php , u can check -> https://prnt.sc/je5cwb

Comment: Can you pastebin the content of `en_data.txt`?

Comment: Check the file permission as well if you're allowed to read from those files.

Comment: @MrBlue This is my test-project until my big project for graduation, my plan is make this test-project 100% fully working, so in `en_data.txt` is just 1 english word and. Hosting where I have this txt. file, Im 100% sure I have reading permissions

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your fopen() lines. fopen not search automatically in root folder. you must defined the / in fopen link this.

```
$czfolder = fopen("/cz_data.txt", "r");
$enfolder = fopen("/en_data.txt", "r");
```

Comment: I did, still nothing

Comment: maybe a dot (.) is requires too. i.e. fopen("./cz_data.txt", "r").